Why does a cube show up when running an IFS of this hypertetrahedron?
I was messing around with iterated function systems and ran the chaos game, except instead of using a triangle it uses a hypertetrahedron, and the original function that computes where to place each new point given two points is changed from (ie: $f(A, B) = (A+B) \times 0.5$, to $f(A, B, m) = sin(B-A) \times m$.
Unexpectedly, even though the base fractal is a simplex a cube emerges for higher values of $m$. A near perfect cube filled with what looks like noise seems anomalous(?) - $f(A, B, m) = sin(A+B) \times m$ also results in a cube.

The beginning of the animation is the IFS with low values of $m$ - it becomes a cube when $m \approx 1$. Also because the game is running in 4D, each frame is just a 3D slice of the 4D fractal generated for that value of $m$, although the color of the each point corresponds to the 4th coordinate of each point. A higher resolution video is uploaded here.
The emergence of the sierpinski fractal with the original chaos game makes sense to me, but I'm curious why a cube would emerge from the combination of the higher dimensional version of a triangle and a sine function.
Thanks!

Can you describe precisely how the points are computed?

Sure thing, you mean code? I think I may have made some progress towards an answer as well. I'll add both when I wake up.
